# JDBC access across VNETs

Tags: azure, jdbc, vnet

I have come across the situation in which 'Spark writing via JDBC directly to a canonically defined staging table in another VNET, via a Hub VNET', is not allowed as it is considered unsafe. Does not fit 'Zero Trust' Security.

Middelware solutions are suggested. Is there a way we can still use JDBC in a more safe fashion when on AZURE Backbone?

This answer from elsewhere below is not accepted by various Security Architects as everyone is running on the MS AZURE Backbone - which is true afaik as well.
[image: This below is not accepted by various Security Architects as everyone is running on the MS AZURE Backbone - which is true afaik as well.]